# Routable folder in S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I'm hosting a static website on S3. Everything is working perfectly, expect that S3 somehow doesn't know that when someone types mysite/folder in the browser, s3 must fetch the content index.html under myseite/folder/index.html.

Is there anything I can do to accomplish that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your bucket for **Static Website Hosting**:

[image]

I tested this and it works for folders too, so:

- `http://mybucket.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com` redirected to `/index.htm`
- `http://mybucket.s3-website-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/folder/` redirected to `/folder/index.htm`

See documentation: [Configure Your Bucket as a Website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-hosting-your-website.html#configure-bucket)

Comment: I've already done that. I ended up finding it was a problem with the DNS. Thank you :)